# Where can I find message for Update-Location-Request?

Tags: diameter-protocol

*I hope you all doing well! I need message format for the Update Location request*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Please check this screenshot this may be helped you

Answer (score 0):

You should also take a look at the following specification: "ETSI TS 129 272" and check the ULR ABNF:

[image: ULR ABNF]